# Grub2 not updating boot list. Booting with error: Failed to set MokListKT: Invalid Parameter

Tags: boot, server, grub2, 16.04, uefi

I am trying to get my dell r610 booting and I've been running into a few problems.

The only OS that I am trying to run on my machine is Ubuntu server 16.04 LTS. I already have it installed and can boot (with UEFI) into it manually with the grub console. However it is nowhere to be seen in the grub boot menu. The only option for boot is "Ubuntu" which just shows a blank screen when selected.

My root is `/dev/sda2` with `sda1` of type `EFI System` and `sda3` of type `Linux swap`.

### What I've tried so far

1. I've run `update-grub` multiple times and it seems to recognize my os with the following output:

```
    Generating grub configuration file ...
    Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-22-generic
    Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-22-generic
    done
```

2. I ran `grub-install /dev/sda` a few times which completed without error but made no changes.
3. For the UEFI boot error (`Failed to set MokListKT: Invalid Parameter`), I found [this](https://marcin.juszkiewicz.com.pl/2016/04/05/failed-to-set-moklistrt-invalid-parameter/) which I followed and set the timeout to be 3s. The error persisted.
4. I also went into `/etc/default/grub` and commented out `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0` and added `GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER="false"`

I really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

running `grub-install` overwrote your UEFI grub with a regular BIOS one.
You need to run `grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/dev/sda1 --bootloader-id=grub` as root and then `grub-update`

Comment: Ok I ran the command and it gave me the error: `grub-install: error: failed to get canonical path of 'udev'.`

Comment: Oh I fixed it by changing the --efi-directory.
`grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot/efi --bootloader-id=grub`

Comment: yeah you're right, sorry for the mistake